# getting error while replacing the single quotes from text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box with tinyMCE editor, i am giving some text from that text box with single quotes, but in query it is showing syntax error

I am trying to remove the single quotes by this

```
txbCaption.Text = txbCaption.Text.Replace("'", "''");
```

and my query

```
public void UpdateCaptions(Hashtable hashtable)
        {
            if (hashtable != null)
            {
                foreach (int key in hashtable.Keys)
                {
                    string query = "update Image set Description='" + hashtable[key] + "' where Id=" + key;
                    // in this query i am getting error
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Conn, CommandType.Text, query);
                }
            }
       }
```

first i am calling replace Text.Replace("'", "''");
after that i am assigning this to

```
if (ViewState["imgIdCapHtbl"] != null)
     imgIdCapHtbl = (Hashtable)ViewState["imgIdCapHtbl"];
int index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["pSelecectedImgIndex"]);

if (imgIdCapHtbl != null && imgIdCapHtbl.ContainsKey(imgIds[index]))
         imgIdCapHtbl[imgIds[index]] = txbCaption.Text;
```

and imgIdCapHtbl hashtable key i am sending to query for saving discription

when i am giving the single quotes in my text then in query 2 times single quotes is getting added.

I used regular exp. validation also but because of TinyMCE editor its not working for that.

some one plz tell me how to replace single quotes, I want if user wants to give single to with text then text box should accept the single quotes and my data gets save without any error,

Comment: Can you show us the exact SQL string you're using?

Comment: If you are replacing the single quotes so that your database query will work correctly, you are probably much better off by using SqlCommand and SqlParameter in the query.  This enables you to create your query without having to worry about special characters in the string you are sending in as a parameter.

Comment: @Alex query which i have posted is same as i am using in my code..
 and while debugging i am getting string like this
update Image set Description=''Test'' where Id=1248

Comment: I meant an example of your ExecuteNonQuery with the full string. Because escaping ' works with ''. So "update Image Set Description ='''Test'....."; adds 'Test into the DB. But as GTG suggested, you might as well use SqlCommand / SqlParameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build a SQL string in that fashion; you've opened yourself up to SQL injection. Optimally, use a stored procedure with parameters. You can also use a parameterized query, such as:

```
string query = "update Image set Description=@description where Id=@id";
```

Then you add your parameters to the SQLCommand as follows:

```
commandToExecute.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",hashtable[key]);
commandToExecute.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",key);
```